# How query to array of categories to get posts in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi in my site I want to show posts that result of selected-multi category by checkboxes input. I fetch categories in URL with "-" separator and explode to an array. my question is here, how get posts by Using categories array names? relationship between posts and categories is many to many.

sending data to posts url:

```
    public function filter(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $cat_Name="";
        if(!empty($data['categoryFilter'])){
            foreach($data['categoryFilter'] as $cat){
                if(empty($cat_Name)){
                    $cat_Name = "&cat_Name=".$cat;
                }else{
                    $cat_Name .= "-".$cat;
                }
            }
        }

        $finalUrl = "posts"."?".$cat_Name;
        return redirect::to($finalUrl);
    }
```

receiving data from url and explode to an array:

```
    if(!empty($_GET['cat_Name'])){
        $categoryArray = explode('-',$_GET['cat_Name']);
    }
```

now I want the query to get posts that have existed categories in $categoryArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `Post` and `Category`,

you can just use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to find the posts that have categories with that `cat_name`:

```php
Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryArray) {
    return $q->whereIn('cat_name', $categoryArray);
});
```

and just use `request` to get the parameters instead of `$_GET`:

```php
public function yourActionName(Request $request)
{
    if(!empty($request->input('cat_Name')){
       $categoryArray = explode('-', $request->input('cat_Name'));
       $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryArray) {
           return $q->whereIn('cat_name', $categoryArray);
       })->get(); 
    } else {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```